# Issue with blobs (Cassandra driver, Python)

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise

As part of testing, I'm using the Cassandra Python driver for trying to select and delete all rows on one of the tables generated by the Cassandra stress tool (Standard1, on Keyspace1). Standard1 consists of several blob columns.

My approach is to extract the (primary) key for the rows and then run a loop to delete the rows based on that.

The problem I'm facing is that it looks like the Cassandra driver converts the blobs (hex bytes) to strings, so when i try to pass that to the delete statement it fails with "cannot parse 'XXXXXX' as hex bytes".

The data in the table on CQLSH looks like "0x303038333830343432", whereas the below select extracts the keys as, i.e., '069672027'.

Is there any way of preventing the hex bytes from being converted into strings? Any other approach i should be using?

Thanks!

```
query  = SimpleStatement("SELECT (key) FROM \"Standard1\" LIMIT 10", consistency_level=ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_QUORUM)
rows = session.execute(query)
for row in rows:
     query = SimpleStatement("DELETE FROM \"Standard1\" WHERE key = %s", consistency_level=ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_QUORUM)
     session.execute(query, (row.key, ))
```

Answer (score 0):

When using simple (unprepared) statements, you need to create a buffer from the string in order for the encoder to recognize it as a blob type.

http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/getting_started.html#type-conversions

Try this:

```
session.execute(query, (buffer(row.key),)
```

Alternatively, binding a prepared statement would do that implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but you can also convert it directly by encoding in hex and prepending `0x`. for example:

```
'0x{}'.format(row.key.encode('hex'))
```